# How to retrieve data that used array in WHERE clause?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

In cakephp, I used $rNo array in WHERE clause.

```
$rooms =$this->find('all',array(    
        'conditions'=>array("NOT"=>array('Room.id'=>$rNo)),
        'group'=>array('Room.room_type_id')));
```

Now, I wanan use query statment by using array in where clause.
How can I use? Please explain me!

```
SELECT * FROM room WHERE id = **array**
```

I wanna know about this **array**. How to use?

Comment: For SQL you can use IN function - SELECT * FROM room WHERE id IN (1,2,3). Is this what you want?

Comment: In debug mode (debug > 0) cake displays your queries at the bottom. Just take a look there and you will find the corresponding SQL query run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard usage (don't know about cakePHP much):

```
SELECT * from `table` where `id` in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Be careful, check you PHP array is not empty because

```
SELECT * from `table` where `id` in ()
```

raises a MySQL error